# Numerical evaluation by NSum at different values

Tags: numerics, summation

I have the following code:

```
NSum[(-1)^(i + j + i*j)* Exp[(-t*Pi)/2*(i^2 + j^2)],{i,-Infinity, Infinity}, {j, -Infinity, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 30, Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 40]
```

I want to evaluate this at a list of different values of `t` at once, say

```
t={1/1000,1/100,1/10,1,2,5/4,3}
```

How can I achieve this? It will be nice to display the results as table/matrix of two column, too; values of `t` and its respective evaluation.

Comment: You could define a function `aymane[t_?NumericQ] := NSum[(* stuff *)]`...

Comment: Thank you, I already did that. now how I evaluate in a set of values, can you give me some hints because I am beginner user. how I achieve the table look?

Comment: Look up `Table[]` and `Grid[]`, then.

Comment: Thank you. I come up with this `Grid[{{1/1000, 1/100, 1/10, 1, 2, 5/4, 3}, 
  Table[aymane[i], {i, {1/1000, 1/100, 1/10, 1, 2, 5/4, 3}}]}]` But I remarked that Grid round the numerical values.

Comment: @J.M. Can you help me with this problem, because I want all the decimals without any rounding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a start:

```
Clear@sum
sum[t_?NumericQ] := {t, 
  NSum[(-1)^(i + j + i*j)*Exp[(-t*Pi)/2*(i^2 + j^2)], {i, -Infinity, 
    Infinity}, {j, -Infinity, Infinity}, NSumTerms -> 30, 
   Method -> "AlternatingSigns", WorkingPrecision -> 40]}

out = sum /@ {1/1000, 1/100, 1/10, 1, 2, 5/4, 3};

Grid[{{"t", "sum"}}~Join~Chop[out], Frame -> All, Alignment -> "."]
```

[image]